# How to move Unity Launcher on boot automatically?

Tags: unity

How can I run this command, which it transfers the unity from one screen to another on computer boot?

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --primary
```

I have tried the suggestion from this article but it doesn't work: https://superuser.com/questions/685471/how-can-i-run-a-command-after-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to open "Automatically Started Applications" from dash and add there this command.

If it does not work, try to add it as

```
 sleep 10;xrandr --output VGA1 --primary
```

Another way is to add it to [SeatDefaults] section of /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf as

```
 display-setup-script=xrandr --output VGA1 --primary
```

I am not 100% sure it will work as a command in lightdm. It can be also be done as a script.

You can create a text file `display.sh` with this content

```
#!/bin/sh
display-setup-script=xrandr --output VGA1 --primary
```

run `chmod +x display.sh`

and then add to lightdm.conf

```
display-setup-script=<path_to_display.sh>
```